# How to use Xpath correct on the following example

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm an Xpath newbie and now I want to know how to locate the following element in the following html.

Element:

```
href="/Kategorien/Installation/c/HGEHK0010"
```

Sorry for that image, I don´t know how to copy it directly from the HTML-page.

Html:

[image: Sorry for that image, I don´t know how to copy it directly from the HTML-page]

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the `<span>` tag:

  ```
  //span[text()='Installation']
  ```
- Using the parent `<a>` and child `<span>` tags:

  ```
  //a[starts-with(@href, '/Kategorien/Installation/c') and ]//span[text()='Installation']
  ```